# ngx-electron-fresh is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular, electron

I have a project with Angular and Electron
I install and import ngx-electron-fresh

This is my "app.module.ts":

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron-fresh';

import { Radice } from './radice';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Radice
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxElectronModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Radice]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But it give me the following error:
"'NgxElectronModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class"
and
"This likely means that the library (ngx-electron-fresh) which declares NgxElectronModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy"

"package.json"

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
"ngx-electron-fresh": "^1.0.9",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
...
}

"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
"electron": "^27.0.4",
...
}
```

I check the compatible version, but it wasn't helpful

Comment: Not much to do, the author needs to update the lib to be ivy compatible

Comment: I already have the most updated version of the library "ngx-electron-fresh".
maybe I could get a less updated version of Angular

Comment: That's a bad idea, the lib relies on Angular v8. That's a very very old version.

Answer (score 0):

`ngx-electron-fresh` is old libray based on Angular 8, so pre-ivy.

I won't rely on it but since its only made of few files, you could directly copy them in you project (and credit the original author).